# Find Difference in hour by passing date filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Table data :

```
ID          FromDate                    ToDate
1           2018-12-07 12:25:47.000     2018-12-07 18:28:44.150
2           2018-12-07 18:28:44.150     2018-12-07 22:33:11.867
3           2018-12-07 22:33:11.867     2018-12-08 03:14:16.630
4           2018-12-08 03:14:16.630     2018-12-09 02:10:44.723
```

This is my query to fetch hour difference

```
Select DATEDIFF(HH,FromDate,TODate) As Hour,* from Test Where FromDate Between '2018-12-07 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'
or ToDate Between '2018-12-07 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'

Select DATEDIFF(HH,FromDate,TODate) As Hour,* from Test Where FromDate Between '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 12:25:47.000'
or ToDate Between '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 12:25:47.000'
```

My Output For 1st query should be

```
6
4
5
9
```

And for 2nd Query output should be

```
14
```

Reason : My Fourth data comes under both query output but i only need hour difference between my date range which i am passing in select query

Comment: So you want your last date in todate to be the filter you have.

Comment: Would you share what is your expected output?

Comment: My Last row in Both the query should give me the difference in hour as per the date which i am passing.For Ex : For 1 st query my last low should give me the difference like DateDIFF(hh,'2018-12-08 03:14:16.630','2018-12-08 12:25:47.000') And for Second Query DateDIFF(hh,'2018-12-08 12:25:47.000','2018-12-09 02:10:44.723')

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
declare @table table (id int ,fromdate datetime,todate datetime)
insert into @table
values

(1           ,'2018-12-07 12:25:47.000','2018-12-07 18:28:44.150'),
(2           ,'2018-12-07 18:28:44.150','2018-12-07 22:33:11.867'),
(3           ,'2018-12-07 22:33:11.867','2018-12-08 03:14:16.630'),
(4           ,'2018-12-08 03:14:16.630','2018-12-09 02:10:44.723')

declare @todate datetime = '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'
declare @fromdate datetime = '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'


Select case when @todate > todate then DATEDIFF(HH,FromDate,TODate) else
datediff(HH,fromdate,@todate) end As Hour,* from @table Where
( FromDate Between '2018-12-07 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'
or  ToDate Between '2018-12-07 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000')

Select case when @fromdate > fromdate then DATEDIFF(HH,@fromdate,TODate) else datediff(HH,fromdate,todate) end As Hour,* from @table Where FromDate Between '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 12:25:47.000'
or ToDate Between '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 12:25:47.000'
```

Comment: Hello it is working but i need only single query not two different query

Comment: @Virender I dont understand? Do you want 14 or 9 then? - If you want both you can just UNION them.

Comment: I need 9 in first query for 4th row when i pass date range '2018-12-07 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' and 14 for second query for 4th row when i pass date range '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 12:25:47.000' but i need single query which should handle this

Comment: @Virender Ahh you want to switch states so when you type one thing you get one result, and another u get another result. Then you need to make it dynamic

Comment: declare todate datetime = '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'
declare fromdate datetime = '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000' Should not be static otherwise it will create problem

Comment: This date should not be static declare todate datetime = '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'
declare Fromdate datetime = '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'

Comment: If it shouldnt be static how would you then determine the last row? It cannot be done. You cannot use your filters as a pointer since they are hardcoded. This makes no sense,